# LinAlgError: SVD did not converge on pca.fit(X_train)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-science

I am working on a big training dataset (21007 rows, 62 columns) and to reduce the dimensions, I'm using PCA from the sklearn package.
I've imputed the null values (using KNN Imputer), have taken care of the outlier treatment, removed any skewed features, and also normalized the dataset using MinMaxScaler().
When I try to run pca.fit(X_train), I get the error : ***LinAlgError: SVD did not converge***

To confirm if I have any infs or Nans, I also run the code below before PCA:

```
X_train.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
X_train.dropna(inplace = True, axis = 0)
X_train.isnull().values.any() # to confirm the dataset doesn't have any null values
pca = PCA(random_state = 42)
```

Right after this code, when I try to fit the training set, I get the error mentioned.

Weirdly enough, as soon as I run the code block again (working on Jupyter notebook), i.e. without restarting the kernel, then my code works

```
pca.fit(X_train)
pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum()
```

I've double-checked the dataset for any skewed features, null values, infs features, but this issue still pops up.

Package Versions I'm using:

numpy==1.19.5

pandas==1.2.0

scikit-learn==0.24.0

scipy==1.6.0

Comment: Do you have a constant column in your data?

Comment: @FBruzzesi no, I removed all the highly skewed columns. I ran the describe function on the scaled dataframe as well, and checked each column manually. No constant column exists.

Comment: @Kush did u learn what was the issue? I'm facing the same error with my `PCA()` and I'm not sure why... also there are no  `nan` or `inf` values in my training set...